# Azure Devops Pipeline Build Parameters

Tags: azure, powershell, devops

The code below is an API call that will run an azure pipeline but the only problem I am having is I am unable to run it on custom branches and I have tried az commands but with az commands, you can't pass though parameters. My goal is basically I have a pipeline A and I want to run Pipeline B which isn't mind so I can't edit it but Pipeline B takes in a parameter called Tag and I want to pass that though from Pineline A but struggling to do so.

```
$token = -join("$Username", ":", "$PAT")
$headers = @{ 
    Authorization = "Basic "+ [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($token))
    'Content-Type' = "application/json"
}
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{$Company}/{$Team}/_apis/pipelines/{$ProjectID}/runs/?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$pipelineBody=@{
    resources=@{
        repositories=@{
            self=@{
                ref="$Branch"
            }
        }
    }
    templateParameters=@{
        Tag="$Tag"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri `
            -Headers $headers `
            -Body "$pipelineBody" `
            -Method Post `
            #-SkipCertificateCheck `
            #-SkipHttpErrorCheck `
            #-ErrorAction Stop

if($result.StatusCode -ne "200")
{
    throw $result
}

return ($result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).url
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do this.

Comment: Is there any other way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Does the response below help?

Answer (score 0):

You can closely (not directly what you want) achieve this by following below steps:

- [Create single pipeline for Pipeline A (Stage 1) and Pipeline B(Stage 2).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [Add a dependency of Pipeline A(Stage 1) on Pipeline B(Stage 2) that it runs only when Pipeline A succeeds.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- Use Powershell script in `Stage 1` to set a pipeline variable to a value you trying to set for `Stage 2` - using out variable in Powershell script task of ADO.
- Consume the pipeline variable set above in the desired step (of Pipeline B).